# Regex Golf: Cut off everything after the last "/"

Tags: regex, perl

This question is purely cosmetical:

I'd like to remove all text after the last "/" of a given string. So if the input is

```
mkdir -p $DEST/Users/Peter/Dropbox/Public/Vacation/P1000891.jpg
```

the output should be

```
mkdir -p $DEST/Users/Peter/Dropbox/Public/Vacation/
```

(To be precise, it doesn't matter if the last "/" is included in the output or not.)

I've found various ways of doing this, for example:

```
my @templist = split "/", 'mkdir -p $DEST/Users/Peter/Dropbox/Public/Vacation/P1000891.jpg';
print join "/", splice(@templist, 0, -1);
```

Or:

```
my ($a) = 'mkdir -p $DEST/Users/Peter/Dropbox/Public/Vacation/P1000891.jpg' =~ /(.*\/)+(?:[^\/]+)/;
print $a;
```

But I thought this should be achievable using only a regex, maybe with search & replace? Maybe with lookahead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just get rid of all non-slash characters at the end of the string:

```
s|[^/]+$||;
```

By the way, look-ahead is a way to check that something occurs at a later point in the pattern, without actually moving the match position forward.  It is rarely needed for simple matching tasks, but it seems to be over-used a lot by people who don't quite know what it is.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Makes me feel warm inside and at the same time makes me feel stupid for not seeing it myself. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
use File::Basename qw( dirname );
dirname($path)
```

Comment: Not wrong at all, but I was explicitly looking for a regex solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
s/(.*\/).*$/$1/g
```

tested below:

```
> echo "a/b/c/d/e/f/remove this"|perl -pe 's/(.*\/).*$/$1/g'
a/b/c/d/e/f/
```

Comment: Yes, but there is no need to match all of the stuff in the string.  You only need to match the part that you want to delete.  Also, it is better to use `[^/]*` than `.*` for the part you want to delete.  It is more specific and therefore makes it easier to write a reliable regex.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned both *regex* and *perl* as tags. The problem (as you've discovered) is that regular expressions are greedy. There are two ways to handle this issue:

- **The old method**: In older versions of `grep` and `sed`, you have a limited set of regular expressions. What you do is take advantage of the fact you don't want any slashes in what you're removing.

Thus:

```
$directory =~ s(/[^/]+$)();
```

(I'm using the parentheses as regular expression separators so I don't have the hill and valleys affect like this: `s/\/[^\/]//`). What this is saying is to match from the end all now forward slash characters that is preceded by a forward slash, and then substitute nothing.

However, it merely looks like you want to remove the file name from a directory. Perl has a built in way of handling this. It's called the `dirname` function:

```
use File::Basename;

[...];

print "mkdir -p " . dirname $directory . "\n";
```

This makes it very, very clear exactly what you're doing. Plus, it will work on *alternative* operating systems that don't use the standard forward slash for directory separation (*cough* Windows! *cough*)

Answer (score 0):

Previous solutions are better than mine, but I'd like to share it with you:

```
perl -e 'my $str = "mkdir -p \$DEST/Users/Peter/Dropbox/Public/Vacation/P1000891.jpg"; my ($res)=$str=~m|(.+/)|; print $res;'
```

prints:

> mkdir -p $DEST/Users/Peter/Dropbox/Public/Vacation/

So, `m|(.+/)|` greedily gobbles everything up until the last "/". Then we say that there should be a "/" in the part we are concerned about.